# how do you resize a background image using HTML dom?

Tags: html, simple-html-dom

```
document.body.style.background = "#f3f3f3 url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2830/9163069867_9c5ee85409_b.jpg') no-repeat right top";
```

How do you resize the background image within this HTML DOM style

http://w3schools.bootcss.com/jsref/prop_style_background.html
i have been using this link as help and it says you can edit the size but i do not know how

Comment: Did you read the whole page in the link you posted? You can specify the size in the background-value: `object.style.background="color image repeat attachment position size origin clip|initial|inherit"`. You can btw also use `object.style.backgroundSize="60px 120px"` to set the background size.

Answer (score 0):

Anwser is on the very same w3school website.

[For your references](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)